# Is there a way to use hg record with ediff?

Tags: emacs, mercurial, emacs-ediff

I've used `hg record` to great effect lately, but it's pretty cumbersome. Emacs `ediff` is a great merge tool, but I haven't seen any way to get it to work with `hg record`. Is there something I can stick in my .hgrc that will let me use `ediff` with `hg record`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `record` command/extension won't launch alternate tools.  If you have uncommitted changes and you want to record only some of them you could use this process:

```
hg revert path/to/thefile  # resets the file back to the last committed version and saves modfied file in thefile.orig
ediff thefile thefile.orig # "merge" any changes you want comitted from .orig into thefile
hg commit # commit the changes you want
mv thefile.orig thefile    # put the uncomitted changes back in place
```

Personally, I just commit everything early and often -- having uncommitted data scares the bajezus out of me.  If you want a way to keep work-in-progress data committed but flexible check out Mercurial queues.